# eliminate repeated sublists from list

Tags: r

I have two equal sublists and would like to eliminate those lists that are repeated and provide the result in a list format. Is there any function that could do this like intersect or unique is applied to vectors. I know I could unlist and then use unique and then do relist again on the prior structure, but would like to know if there is a function thatcan do the same for lists than for vectors. I know also I could use reduce as to simplify the list and then apply the sugestion below by @akrun. However I am looking for solutions as to be able to work with lists with complex sublists.

```
TER <- list(list(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3,4)),list(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3,4)))

TER 
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

# Desired Output.

TER

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Do you need it to be list of lists?  Otherwise `unique(do.call(c, TER))`

Comment: @ akrun - Yes as the function above will only work for lists.

Comment: # You are right Editing it appologies

Comment: One option would be `i1 <- duplicated(do.call(c, TER), fromLast=TRUE);Filter(length, Map('[', TER, split(i1, rep(1:2, each =2))))`

Comment: Wow, I was looking for a simple base function in R or from some package, however this seems to work.

Comment: `unique` works on "list"s too; `unique(TER)` seems to give your output unless I'm missing something

Comment: @ Alexis you are right fool of me used Map(unique,TER)

Comment: @Barnaby I changed TER slightly and applied my solution.  Please check if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `duplicated` to return the logical index, then with `Map` and the `Filter` we subset the `list`

```
l1 <- do.call(c, TER)
i1 <- duplicated(l1, fromLast=TRUE)|!duplicated(l1)
Filter(length, Map('[', TER, split(i1, rep(seq_along(TER), lengths(TER)))))
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Suppose if the TER is

```
TER <- list(list(c(1,2,3),c(1,3,3,4)),list(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3,4)))
```

It gives the output

```
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 3 3 4


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```